# Apache JMeter 4 - Can I get a text summary of a load test?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I'm looking for a way to generate a text summary at the end of a load test, that is similar to what the GUI shows, but when running headless. I'm looking for the information in the area I've got the box around. Is there a method to do that?

Edit: I see there's a "`Save table data`" button at the bottom of the screen, that saves a file exactly like what I'm looking for. But I'm looking for how to do that in headless mode.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I did to get what I was looking for, found parts in several different places, here's what you need to do. Note that I was installing my plugins via zip files.

**Plugins** - Unzip these in the top level directory where JMeter is installed
jpgc-cmd-2.2.zip
jpgc-synthesis-2.2.zip
jpgc-filterresults-2.2.zip

**Generate jtl file during run**
/path/to/bin/jmeter -n -t /path/to/TestPlan.jmx  **-l /path/to/output.jtl**

**Generate the csv file**
/path/to/bin/JMeterPluginsCMD.sh  --tool Reporter --generate-csv "/path/to/Aggregate_Report.csv" --input-jtl "/path/to/output.jtl" --plugin-type AggregateReport

Edit for **@usersam**

My toplevel directory is "apache-jmeter-5.0"
so if I

```
> cd apache-jmeter-5.0
> ls -l 
total 1567
-rwxrwxrwx    1 AvonNied UsersGrp     14569 Sep 14  2018 LICENSE
-rwxrwxrwx    1 AvonNied UsersGrp       167 Sep 14  2018 NOTICE
-rwxrwxrwx    1 AvonNied UsersGrp      9946 Sep 14  2018 README.md
drwxrwxrwx    1 AvonNied UsersGrp         0 Oct 15 13:05 backups
drwxrwxrwx    1 AvonNied UsersGrp         0 Oct 15 13:18 bin
drwxrwxrwx    1 AvonNied UsersGrp         0 Aug 24  2019 docs
drwxrwxrwx    1 AvonNied UsersGrp         0 Aug 24  2019 extras
-rwxrwxrwx    1 AvonNied UsersGrp      1815 Oct 15 14:32 jmeter.log
-rwxrwxrwx    1 AvonNied UsersGrp   1029072 Feb 15  2019 jpgc-cmd-2.2.zip
-rwxrwxrwx    1 AvonNied UsersGrp   1028911 Feb 15  2019 jpgc-filterresults-2.2.zip
-rwxrwxrwx    1 AvonNied UsersGrp   1014486 Feb 15  2019 jpgc-synthesis-2.2.zip
drwxrwxrwx    1 AvonNied UsersGrp         0 Aug 24  2019 lib
drwxrwxrwx    1 AvonNied UsersGrp         0 Aug 24  2019 licenses
drwxrwxrwx    1 AvonNied UsersGrp         0 Aug 24  2019 printable_docs
```

You can see that the zip files are present there, and that's where I unzipped them. For example, one of the files contained in the "jpgc-cmd-2.2.zip" file is "lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar".

```
> pwd
apache-jmeter-5.0
> ls -l lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar
-rwxrwxrwx    1 AvonNied UsersGrp    211778 Oct  3  2018 lib/jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.6.jar
```

Comment: One small doubt. jpgc-cmd-2.2.zip when extract, it has bin and lib folders. And Jmeter also have bin and lib folders. so where exactly to put this three extract directories. I tried with putting all 3 unzipped folders with jmeter installation but it gave me error, "ERROR: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.jorphan.logging.LoggingManager".  please put directory structure snapshot if possible.

Comment: See updated answer, I feel like maybe your error is related to something else, not the place where you unzipped the files.

Comment: Thanks @Adam. Now it is working. I put the zip files as you mentioned and then chose "extract here" for unzipping. it automatically puts files in relevant bin and lib folders.

Comment: @usersam - Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 2):

1. Any reason for not using the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)? You can run your test like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl -e -o report
   ```

   once your test finishes you will be able to open `index.html` file under `report` folder with your favorite web browser and enjoy the test summary along with charts

   [image]
2. There is [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) which is capable of generating tables and charts out of the .jtl results file. You can install the Command Line Graph Plotting Tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)
3. [According to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5) (or whatever is the latest version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) on next available opportunity